# Problems centreing images in bxslider slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css, bxslider

I'm having problems centreing the images in this slideshow (using bxslider) - 
http://badsekta.com/trix/collection.html

I've tried various methods via Google for several days but find myself stuck, so any help or advice is much appreciated!

Thanks,

Will

---

```
HTML >

        <header>
      <div id="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html" title="Home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="collection.html" title="Collection">Collection</a></li>
          <li><a href="shop.html" title="Shop">Shop</a></li>
          <li><a href="faq-policies.html" title="Frequently asked questions and policies">FAQ/Policies</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.php" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
        <br class="clearboth"/>
      </div>
    </header>
    <br>
    <div class="table">
      <table width="600px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="1" align="left" valign="middle"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="" width="504" height="139"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="1" align="left" valign="middle">COLLECTION</td>
        </tr>
             <td colspan="1" align="center" valign="middle">
                 <ul class="bxslider">
      <li><img src="assets/img/collection-slider-images/1.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="assets/img/collection-slider-images/2.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="assets/img/collection-slider-images/3.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="assets/img/collection-slider-images/4.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="assets/img/collection-slider-images/5.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="assets/img/collection-slider-images/6.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="assets/img/collection-slider-images/7.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="assets/img/collection-slider-images/8.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="assets/img/collection-slider-images/9.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="assets/img/collection-slider-images/10.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
    </tr>
    </td>
      </table>
    </div>

CSS >

header {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}
.table {
    margin-left: 75px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top:300px;
}
/* Nav menu */
#nav {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    padding-left: 66px;
    text-align:center;
}
#nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    text-align:center;
}
#nav a:link, #nav a:visited {
    color: #ae55ed;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav a {
    padding: 12px 16px;
}
#nav a:hover {
    padding: 12px 16px;
    color: #F00;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
    position: relative;
}
#nav li:before {
    content: " | ";
    color: #fff;
}
#nav li:first-child:before {
    content: none;
}
#nav li li {
    width: 160px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
#nav li:hover {
    color: #F00;
}
#nav li li:hover {
    color: #F00;
}
#nav ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: -2px;
    border: solid 1px transparent;
}
#nav li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
/** RESET AND LAYOUT
===================================*/

.bx-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto 60px;
    padding: 0;
 *zoom: 1;
}
.bx-wrapper img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/** THEME
===================================*/

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
    border:  3px solid #fff;
    left: -3px;
    background: #fff;
    /*fix other elements on the page moving (on Chrome)*/
    -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
    -moz-transform: translatez(0);
    -ms-transform: translatez(0);
    -o-transform: translatez(0);
    transform: translatez(0);
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager, .bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
    width: 100%;
}
/* LOADER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-loading {
    min-height: 50px;
    background: url(images/bx_loader.gif) center center no-repeat #fff;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
}
/* PAGER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: Ubuntu;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #666;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager .bx-pager-item, .bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-controls-auto-item {
    display: inline-block;
 *zoom: 1;
 *display: inline;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a {
    background: #666;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    outline: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:hover, .bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active {
    background: #000;
}
/* DIRECTION CONTROLS (NEXT / PREV) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-prev {
    left: 10px;
    background: url(images/controls.png) no-repeat 0 -32px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-next {
    right: 10px;
    background: url(images/controls.png) no-repeat -43px -32px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-prev:hover {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-next:hover {
    background-position: -43px 0;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -16px;
    outline: 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a.disabled {
    display: none;
}
/* AUTO CONTROLS (START / STOP) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
    text-align: center;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 11px;
    outline: 0;
    background: url(images/controls.png) -86px -11px no-repeat;
    margin: 0 3px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start:hover, .bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start.active {
    background-position: -86px 0;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 9px;
    height: 11px;
    outline: 0;
    background: url(images/controls.png) -86px -44px no-repeat;
    margin: 0 3px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop:hover, .bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop.active {
    background-position: -86px -33px;
}
/* PAGER WITH AUTO-CONTROLS HYBRID LAYOUT */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-pager {
    text-align: left;
    width: 80%;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-controls-auto {
    right: 0;
    width: 35px;
}
/* IMAGE CAPTIONS */

.bx-wrapper .bx-caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #666\9;
    background: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.75);
    width: 100%;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-caption span {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Ubuntu;
    display: block;
    font-size: .85em;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please include enough code in the question to reproduce the problem. Other way downvoters will make his work :P

Comment: OK sorry - only started posting here yesterday so still getting used to the best way to craft questions... Will update my question shortly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .bxslider element has 40px of padding-left (and 16px of margin) on it which is pushing the images out of alignment, so just add the following to your css:

```
.bxslider {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for that - working 100%! Been staring at the code too long to notice, so much appreciated!